# Shifting element in Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having an arraylist .I want to place a particular element to first index if that is present in the list . For that I am iterating the list , and checking .If suppose I find element A in the list , say at index 2 ,I will add that element to the first index . By this ,the element would be added and the list would be shifted downwards . But , the problem is this will create duplicate element .

So my requirement is to put a particular list element to the first index . How can I effectively achieve this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just swap the values? Let's say, you are looking for value "2". You find "2" in index 4... just swap value at index 4 with value at index 0 (first entry). You will have "2" in the first slot without adding any duplicates.

Comment: yep ,the logic is swapping . I used collections.swap method for swapping . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
public void shift(List list, int index){
    list.add(0, list.remove(index))
}
```

This will remove the element at given `index` and put it at the beginning of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Swapping two elements of list:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    String elementToSwap = "2";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add( "1" );
    list.add( "2" );
    list.add( "3" );
    int index = list.indexOf( elementToSearch );
    if ( index >= 0 ) {
      String temp = list.get( 0 );
      list.set( 0, elementToSearch );
      list.set( index, temp );
    }
    System.out.println( list );
  }
```

Comment: I used collections.swap method for swapping instead. Thanks